# Dual channel: mix a current kit of memory sticks with another from 3 years ago?

Tags: memory, dual-channel

My PC has 8Gb. of memory, in 2x4Gb. memory sticks bought 3 years ago, and is currently working with dual channel enabled. I'm thinking of adding another 8 Gb., but the problem is that, for dual channel to keep working, the new memory sticks that I buy should be of exactly the same kind that the current ones.

I've searched the net, and the manufacturer (Geil) still exists, and is currently making sticks with the same specs than the ones I have: DDR3-1066, 1333 Mhz, CAS 9-9-9-24, voltage 1.5V... So, can I be confident that these new chips will work nicely in dual channel with my current ones, or is there some other odd feature that might prevent so?

Comment: Depends on motherboard. Some (like mine) can't take more than 2GB of total RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/290085-30-same-speed-revision-mismatch-causing-single-channel-mode) link it possibly/probably won't work unless the revision of the memory is identical.  The bottom line is that it depends on the motherboard and the differences in the installed memory - sometimes it will work, sometimes not.   You may also want to research if the difference of running dual channel memory is substantial enough to be worried about.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Intel website, it would work. The following is taken from their website:

```
Rules to enable dual-channel mode
To achieve dual-channel mode, the following conditions must be met:

    Same memory size (1 GB, 2 GB, 4 GB, etc.)
    Matched DIMM configuration in each channel
    Matched in symmetrical memory slots 

Configurations that do not match the above conditions will revert to single-channel mode. 
The following conditions do not need to be met:

    Same brand
    Same timing specifications
    Same speed (MHz)
```

Source: http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/cs-011965.htm

Personally, however, I would much prefer to have the exact same ram in each slot. If this isn't an option, it should work though. Hope this helps.